# PhoneGap app test app not runing giving error

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have installed the phone gap in mac but when i select xcode project as phone gap app then it does not have www folder in it and when i run it gives error exit bin like this .
I am using xcode 3..2.6 and i have also 4 on both same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your www folder to your project in Xcode and choose 'create folder references for any added folders' from the popup and click 'Finish'. You will find www folder where your .xcodeproj is.

Comment: it is not there i am using cordova lib latest version